# How to use VC++ to save data into an excel file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, c++-cli

I am new to VC++. I need to save data into an excel file. Please give me some direction. I have no clue where to start. Please help

Thanks

Comment: Going by the C++/CLI tag, you'll want to use the classes in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace.  This kind of code isn't typically written in C++/CLI, Type::Missing isn't that pretty and there are no code samples to guide you but can certainly work.

Comment: Is there complex formatting in the excel file (graphs, etc)?  If it's pure data, the simplest solution is to create a Comma-Separated-Value file (*.csv) since you can do this with built-in text streams, and Excel knows how to import it.

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus is a library that allows to write and read excel files. I used it in c#, but I know it works in vb.net, so it should work for C++ as well since it's a dll.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to write tabular data, one of the easiest solutions is to use ADO. You can perform an SQL INSERT query to write rows of data on an Excel worksheet: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Answer (score 0):

[OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-api.aspx) is another solution you may wish to check out. It's .NET so you'd link it in like EEPlus. [Evals are free](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-free-evaluation-b.aspx). It's pretty powerful, so it may be overkill depending on what exactly you are trying to generate. Also, disclaimer, I'm one of the engineers who built the latest version.